# QT5 Creator 'follow symbol under cursor' not referencing correct file

Tags: qt5, qt-creator

I have two sets of files in my project, one of them a modified version with a different name. When I select 'Follow Symbol Under Cursor', it jumps to the object definitions in the modified file set even though it's not supposed to. The folders for both files are in the same directory. Is there any way to manually set a different file reference or correct this?